# How to get coefficients for sine/cosine function from complex FFT in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm working on a control system that measures the movement of a vibrating robot arm. Because there is some deadtime, I need to look into the future of the somewhat noisy signal.
My idea was to use the frequencies in the sampled signal and produce a fourier function that could be used for extrapolation.

My question: I already have the FFT of the signal vector (containing 60-100 values e.g.) and can see the main frequencies in the amplitude spectrum. Now I want to have a function f(t) which fits to the signal, removes some noise, and can be used to predict the near future of the signal. How do I calculate the coefficients for the sine/cosine functions out of the complex FFT data?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You might want to try asking this on http://dsp.stackexchange.com as it's more DSP-related than programming-related

Comment: Okay I didnt know about that site! I will try it there!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR FFT essentially produces output as a sum of sine functions with different frequencies. The importance of each frequency is the height of each peak. So what you really want to do here is filter out some frequencies (ie. high frequencies for the arm to move gently) and then come back to the time domain.

In matlab this should be like going through the vector of what you got from fft, setting some values to 0 (or doing something more complex to it) and then use ifft to come back to time domain and make the prediction based on what you get.

There's also one thing you should consider while doing this - Nyquist frequency - this means that the highest frequency that you get on your fft is half of the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an FFT for data that isn't periodic within the FFT aperture length, then you may need to use a window to reduce spurious frequencies due to "spectral leakage".  Frequency estimation techniques to better estimate "between bin" frequency content may also be appropriate.  The phase of each cosine sinusoid, relative to the edge of the window, is usually atan2(imag[i], real[i]).  The frequency depends on the sample rate and bin number versus the length of the FFT.

You might also want to look into using a Kalman filter instead of an FFT.

Added: If your signal isn't exactly integer periodic in the FFT length, then you may want to do an fftshift before the FFT to move the resulting phase measurement reference point to the center of your data vector, instead of a possibly discontinuous circular edge.